# Bold @font-face is not loading

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I'm trying to do an eBay listing template - everything works fine in my editor but on eBay the bold and semibold font faces are not loading, for a while only two fonts would load, now I can get 4 fonts to load. Can anyone see a reason why it wouldn't load all of them?

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'ProximaNova';
  src: url('http://rocketway.net/themebuilder/products/font/proximanova-light-webfont.eot');
  src: url('http://rocketway.net/themebuilder/products/font/proximanova-light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('http://rocketway.net/themebuilder/products/font/proximanova-light-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('http://rocketway.net/themebuilder/products/font/proximanova-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: light;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'ProximaNova';
  src: url('http://rocketway.net/themebuilder/products/font/proximanova-regular-webfont.eot');
  src: url('http://rocketway.net/themebuilder/products/font/proximanova-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('http://rocketway.net/themebuilder/products/font/proximanova-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('http://rocketway.net/themebuilder/products/font/proximanova-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'ProximaNova';
  src: url('http://rocketway.net/themebuilder/products/font/proximanova-semibold-webfont.eot');
  src: url('http://rocketway.net/themebuilder/products/font/proximanova-semibold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('http://rocketway.net/themebuilder/products/font/proximanova-semibold-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('http://rocketway.net/themebuilder/products/font/proximanova-semibold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'ProximaNova';
  src: url('http://rocketway.net/themebuilder/products/font/proximanova-bold-webfont.eot');
  src: url('http://rocketway.net/themebuilder/products/font/proximanova-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('http://rocketway.net/themebuilder/products/font/proximanova-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('http://rocketway.net/themebuilder/products/font/proximanova-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'ProximaNova';
  src: url('http://rocketway.net/themebuilder/products/font/proximanova-thin-webfont.eot');
  src: url('http://rocketway.net/themebuilder/products/font/proximanova-thin-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('http://rocketway.net/themebuilder/products/font/proximanova-thin-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('http://rocketway.net/themebuilder/products/font/proximanova-thin-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: 200;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'ProximaNova';
  src: url('http://rocketway.net/themebuilder/products/font/proximanova-extrabold-webfont.eot');
  src: url('http://rocketway.net/themebuilder/products/font/proximanova-extrabold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('http://rocketway.net/themebuilder/products/font/proximanova-extrabold-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('http://rocketway.net/themebuilder/products/font/proximanova-extrabold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<!-- Text -->
<table style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" class="mobile" border="0" width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" object="drag-module-small">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" width="100%" style="font-size: 47px; color: #ffffff; text-align: center; line-height: 50px; vertical-align: top;">
      <span style="font-family:'ProximaNova', Helvetica; font-weight:900; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">World Class <br>Bespoke Mac Solutions.</span>
```

Comment: What browser does this issue occur on? All of them, or one or two specifically? Some browsers have problems with bolding when specifying a number (font-weight:200) instead of using the other method: lighter, bold, bolder, etc.

Can you post the HTML/CSS? I want to see how you call/reference the font name. There are a few ways that this can be done.

In my sites I give each font a unique "Font-Family" name; when I want bold, I'd call "ProximaNova-Bold" so I know I'm calling the right one.

Comment: Hi Josh, I added the heading which wont use bold or extra bold, here you can also see the full thing in effect at eBay in a fake listing - http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/NEW-Beats-by-Dr-Dre-Solo2-On-Ear-Headband-Headphones-Test-Listing-/301742453131?

Comment: I did use the separate font-family names as you suggest but the site was only parsing two from eBay, now its at least on 4, but when I look at the fonts loaded, neither of the bold fonts are in the font assets on the page. Its happening in all browsers.

Comment: The code below should fix; I listed it separate from this thread. I'm not quite sure what the font is supposed to look like, but when I use DevTools and turn the font CSS off, I see it turn off and revert to the fallback font I declared. Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following and it seems to work in all browsers. Note the third "src" below. It's a bugfix so all the fonts load.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'ProximaNova-Bold';
src: url('http://rocketway.net/themebuilder/products/font/proximanova-bold-webfont.eot');
src: url('http://rocketway.net/themebuilder/products/font/proximanova-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
src:local("â˜º"), 
    url('http://rocketway.net/themebuilder/products/font/proximanova-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('http://rocketway.net/themebuilder/products/font/proximanova-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
```

}

It doesn't look like the bold font was loading into the page.

[image: Screenshot of Loading Assets]

Here's a [Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/WebDevJoshB/pen/xwVZNK) if copy/past helps.

Comment: Hi Josh, thanks for the help! Unfortunately this didn't work - however it led me to find what did work. For some reason eBay seems very very touchy about any unnecessary white space - I deleted this while testing your solution and it worked! Weirdly with eBay and your solution (and my previous way of doing it) it gives "unexpected CSS token" errors unless @font-face is all on one line. Very strange.